# countdown timer with Swift Date

Tags: swift, date

I'm working on implementing a simple countdown timer in Swift using the Foundation [Date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date) struct for precision. I am doing this by comparing the current time with the end time and looping while the difference is more than zero. Here's my code:

```
var timerSeconds = 15.0
var startTime = Date()

var endTime = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: timerSeconds)


print("Start time is \(startTime)")
print("End time is \(endTime)")

var timeRemaining = Date().distance(to: endTime)
while (timeRemaining > 0) {
    print("Time remaining is \(Int(timeRemaining) + 1)")
    sleep(1)
    timeRemaining = Date().distance(to: endTime)
}
print("Done")
```

Is this a good use of Date's functions to implement the timer? Is there a better way to do this using Date?

Comment: Nope, never use `sleep`, never. Use `Timer` instead to peridocally update remaining time (e.g. every 0.1 seconds).

Comment: *Is there a better way to do this using Date?* Yes, using `sleep` is horrible, don't do this, there is `Timer`, `DispatchSourceTimer` or – quite modern – the `Timer` publisher of the Combine framework. The benefit of the latter is that the current date is emitted when the timer fires.

Comment: Thank you @Sulthan and @vadian! I actually used a Timer outside of this example, but what do you think of the use of the Date struct here, e.g. using distance(to:) and init(timeIntervalSinceNow:) to calculate the approp values?

Comment: I would simply decrease `timerSeconds`

Comment: @vadian Please no. Decreasing seconds you will slowly accumulate inaccuracy. `Timer` is not precise, therefore always calculating the remaining time from current time is the correct way to go.

Comment: @Sulthan I think the *precision* of a timer with a 1 sec frequency is negligible. 

Comment: @vadian It is not. If you want continuous updates, you have to trigger the timer at least 3-4 times a second, otherwise the user will see that not every second has the same length. The precision of `Timer` is around 0.05 sec which means that over 30 seconds and 3 repetitions every second, the error can be up to 4.5 seconds! Even if you repeat only once a second, the error will be clearly visible.